# No Mapping Specified Error in Entity Framework 4 with Asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am working with Asp.net MVC3 with Entity Framework 4, I have updated my model and when I compiles my solutions, It shows Build Succeeded at the status bar but showing following error in error dock window

No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - Categories, Users, Roles.

On the running it shows the first page (a login panel) without any error or warning, but when I click the login after after entering credentials it gives me following exception

An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

I am not so much familiar with entity framework, so please help me to resolve the issue.....

Comment: Did you check the parts you changed in the model? Sometimes it leaves an old field without the mappings, remove it and rebuild.

Comment: My Record table had one field with Recoord_Name later I updated the column name in database with Record_Name, and when I upadated the model it updates successfully but the field name was still Recoord_Name, so i deleted the entity from my model and added it again from the database, this time it was fine. But then started the problem of no mapping specified error...

Comment: **See the inner exception for details**

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to get the error rectified:

```
Click on update model, Remove the erroneuos tables, Again click on update model, Add the removed tables, Build your project and it will work now
```

---